# need help in UI threads in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I'm using UI threads and I built one thread with message map and it works fine, the problem is when I'm tring to create another thread from the first one.

When I'm getting to this line:

```
this->PostThreadMessage(WM_MYTHREADMESSAGE,0,0);
```

I'm getting the next message:

> "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed"

I dont know if its could be the reason for the problem but I have built two message maps, one for each thread, I don't know if its ok to do so.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Do you mean `message pump` instead of message maps?

Comment: Also are you getting an exception?  The "No symbols" messages usually occurs when you break in the debugger and no symbols have been found.  In that case, you should download the symbols, see [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503) for starters on how to get windows' debug symbols.

Comment: what is `this` in the call context? is it the instance of the first thread? if so, then you are posting a message to the same thread, which might break things, and does not make much sense.

Comment: What are UI threads? Most sane developers do all the UI inside a single thread. Even if you are sane when you start trying to multi-thread you UI, it won't be long before the onset of insanity.

Comment: @ak im using it from the second thread because i want to send a message from the second thread to the first one. also i have built a message map in the second thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is difficult to understand.  I'm assuming that you're stepping through your program in the debugger, and you get to that `PostThreadMessage` line.

If you choose Step Into, the debugger will try to step into the `PostThreadMessage` call (or the framework wrapper, depending on the type of `this`).  Since `PostThreadMessage` is a system call, it's likely you don't have symbols for that code.  The debugger will just show you disassembly.  You can try to use the Microsoft symbol server, but I don't see much point in trying to trace into `PostThreadMessage`.  If the parameters are right, it's going to post the message to the specified thread's queue.  Not much to see there.

Posting message to other threads is tricky business.  Most Windows programs, even multithreaded ones, typically keep all the UI work to a single thread.  It can be done, but there are a lot of caveats and it's usually not worth the pain.

Answer (score 2):

So there are couple of things:

1. if you want to notify the UI thread from the worker thread, then you should not use `PostThreadMessage`, [here is why](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14720).
2. When `this->PostThreadMessage(...)` called in a member function of thread A, the message will be sent to thread A, because `this` points to `CWinThread` of A. You have to get a pointer to the other thread to post a message to it.
3. Finally if you want to notify your UI thread, use `PostMessage` to send a message to the window created by that thread. Add a corresponding handler to the window message map.

Hope this helps